# MediaWiki update from 1.15 to latest version

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, mediawiki-templates, mediawiki-installation

Would it be possible to upgrade from MediaWiki from **1.15** to the **latest stable** version without losing data? I believe I will have a problem with database tables and extensions.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From personal experience I would recommend to take it easy and upgrade [one major version at a time](https://releases.wikimedia.org/mediawiki/), especially when you do not have much experience with the process. This bite size approach will take longer but in return you will:

- have to deal with fewer issues every time something is not right,
- gradually update the `LocalSettings.php` as you go along every time moving it from the current to new release,
- familiarise yourself with the [Release Notes](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Release_notes) for each version - they contain notes on the configuration and breaking changes among other things, and finally
- get comfortable with the process.

This approach helped me when I was upgrading from 1.27.3 to 1.31.8 first time in years. I came across problems at least twice and could not find relevant information on how to deal with them. The most annoying was no feedback from the `update.php` script or blank page when trying the new installation.

Below I include notes from my experience with updating MediaWiki in case that's of any help to anyone facing a big upgrade. These are just main points, so read the official [Upgrading](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Upgrading) page too.

### Installation

Don't extract a MediaWiki release archive into the existing wiki installation directory. Move the old instance to some backup directory and start afresh. Also make a back-up of the database.

Create a copy of `LocalSettings.php` from the original installation and comment out all custom extensions and skins as they will no longer be present.

Now as you bump the versions up:

- Copy `LocalSettings.php` from the previous instance to the directory created while extracting a release archive. There does not seem to be a way to generate a fresh default `LocalSettings.php` during an upgrade, which would prevent some of the problems.
- Run update script in the `maintenance` directory. There should be some output:

  ```
  $ php update.php

  MediaWiki 1.31.8 Updater
  ...
  ```
- If there is no output at all that means there is likely a problem somewhere in the `LocalSettings.php` configuration. See the Debugging section below.
- You should be able to access the wiki now.
- Get a [release archive](https://releases.wikimedia.org/mediawiki/) of the next major version, read the [Release Notes](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Release_notes) and repeat the steps.

Once you reached the target version you can gradually copy over all the custom changes from the old wiki (extensions, modifications, images, skins etc.) remembering to enable them in `LocalSettings.php`.

Keeping MediaWiki under version control makes it much easier to keep track of any customisations. Just make sure you keep the repository inaccessible to the world.

### Debugging

In order to debug enable the following settings in `LocalSettings.php`:

```
$wgShowExceptionDetails = true;
$wgShowDBErrorBacktrace = true;
$wgShowSQLErrors = true;
```

Now go to the installation page `https://.../mw-config/` (adjust the URL to match your set-up) and you should see some errors that might indicate what is wrong. For example, some skins or extensions from the older version may not supported any longer and you have to disable them in `LocalSettings.php`.

Once the configuration has been updated try again until you get to the web installer.

Once you managed to get to the web installer page stop there and try again with `update.php` script. It should work now. Close the web installer, there won't be any need to run it now.

Once `update.php` has finished you should be able to access the wiki. Disable the debug settings in `LocalSettings.php`.

Comment: For future visitors: if you are upgrading from 1.15 there is no mw-config directory in 1.16. If you do not have remote shell access it will be very difficult for you to perform the upgrade. I suggest "relocating" your wiki to a WAMP server, or similar, and updating until you reach a version where the above instructions are applicable.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, yes - the update mechanism is a big array of database migration scripts, which gets expanded when you upgrade the code, so the number of versions doesn't really matter. In practice, that's a long way to go, so it's very unlikely anyone else has tested that specific upgrade path. Make sure to backup first.

One notable exception is [HitCounter](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:HitCounters) data, which does get dropped, as that functionality was removed from MediaWiki. See that page for workarounds.

Comment: What about exporting the content in XML and re-import it in the new version? I doubt xml format has been altered between versions...

Comment: It [has been](https://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10.xsd) but in theory the changes are backwards-compatible. That will only preserve the content though, not user accounts and various other things.

Comment: indeed it will not